# SQL INSERT INTO simultaneously in 2 tables in apex oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, sql-insert

I have a script:
I write the data in test2!

```
INSERT INTO test2 (val)
SELECT    SUBSTR (:P1_FIRST, 1, 1)
      || TO_CHAR (
            (  TO_NUMBER (REGEXP_SUBSTR (:P1_FIRST, '\d+$'))
             + LEVEL
             - 1))
         AS val
 FROM dual
 CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
                TO_NUMBER (
                   REGEXP_SUBSTR (:P1_LAST, '\d+$'))
             - TO_NUMBER (
                   REGEXP_SUBSTR (:P1_FIRST, '\d+$'))
             + 1;
```

I want to write it in another table myself.I want to write it down all in one request

```
INSERT INTO test3 (val,data_area,data_add )
SELECT    SUBSTR (:P1_FIRST, 1, 1)
      || TO_CHAR (
            (  TO_NUMBER (REGEXP_SUBSTR (:P1_FIRST, '\d+$'))
             + LEVEL
             - 1))
         AS val,
        (select data_area from SEC_USERS_LIST where login =   LOWER(:APP_USER)) as data_area, 
          (select to_char(sysdate, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "Right Now" from dual )  as data_add 
 FROM dual
 CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
                TO_NUMBER (
                   REGEXP_SUBSTR (:P1_LAST, '\d+$'))
             - TO_NUMBER (
                   REGEXP_SUBSTR (:P1_FIRST, '\d+$'))
             + 1;
```

Comment: Why are you inserting the current date as a string? Use a `DATE` column and just insert `SYSDATE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try and use [Oracle `INSERT ALL` syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9014.htm) :

> In a **multitable insert**, you insert computed rows derived from the rows returned from the evaluation of a subquery into one or more tables.
>
> **ALL into_clause**
>
> Specify `ALL` followed by multiple `insert_into_clauses` to perform an unconditional multitable insert. Oracle Database executes each insert_into_clause once for each row returned by the subquery.

Consider:

```
INSERT ALL
INTO test3 (val,data_area,data_add) VALUES (x_val, x_data_area, x_data_add)
INTO test2 (val) VALUES (x_val)
SELECT    SUBSTR (:P1_FIRST, 1, 1)
      || TO_CHAR (
            (  TO_NUMBER (REGEXP_SUBSTR (:P1_FIRST, '\d+$'))
             + LEVEL
             - 1))
         AS x_val,
        (select data_area from SEC_USERS_LIST where login =   LOWER(:APP_USER)) as x_data_area, 
        (select to_char(sysdate, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "Right Now" from dual )  as x_data_add 
 FROM dual
 CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
     TO_NUMBER (REGEXP_SUBSTR (:P1_LAST, '\d+$'))
     - TO_NUMBER (REGEXP_SUBSTR (:P1_FIRST, '\d+$'))
     + 1
;
```

NB: as far as concerns, the inline subquery that returns the current date is not needed and could be simplified as just:

```
to_char(sysdate, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as x_data_add
```

Instead of:

```
(select to_char(sysdate, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "Right Now" from dual )  as x_data_add
```

Even more, as commented by [Thomas Tschernich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1039665/thomas-tschernich): if `x_data_add` is of datatype `DATE`, no casting should be necessary and you could simply use a default on the table column and omit it from the `INSERT` completely

Comment: Even more so, if `x_data_add` is of datatype `DATE`, no casting should be necessary and you could simply use a default on the table column and omit it from the `INSERT` completely.

Comment: All the same where "INSERT ALL" results in the error "ORA-06550: line 1, column 144: PL / SQL: ORA-00905: missing keyword"

Comment: @ThomasTschernich: yes, good point (although OP doesn't tell the target datatype), I added it to my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @AndriiHavrylyak: there was a typo in the query where `INSERT` was repeated multiple times, I just corrected it. Is it working for you now?